# Как присвоить свойствам класса значения свойств другого экземпляра

Tags: php, ооп

Имеется такая конструкция:

```
Class foo{
    public $name;

    function someName() {
        $model = new foo;
        $model->name = 'Vasia';
        if($this->name != 'Vasia) $this = $model; // В этой сроке и нужно присвоить свойства

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Нужно все значения свойств `$model` присвоить `$this`, чтоб явно для каждого свойства не писать `$this->name = $model->name;`

Comment: Может быть вы все-таки хотите инициализировать свойства `$model` из `$this` а не наоборот?

Comment: @РоманМальцев а чем эта функция отличается от просто конструктора, если она копирует свойства свежесозданного объекта того же класса ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас все свойства `public`, попробуйте так:

```
foreach(get_class_vars( get_class($model) ) as $prop) {
    $this->$prop = $model->$prop;
}
```

**UPD**
В комментарии к вопросу был задан правильный вопрос "Может быть вы все-таки хотите инициализировать свойства $model из $this а не наоборот? " (@Dmitriy Simushev). В таком случае вам подойдет:

```
$model = clone $this;
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: вариант с foreach мне подходит, спасибо.